# Android: openStream fails on URL object

Tags: java, android

I am trying to test-download a file on android but it fails. In the code, I am first opening a stream from a URL object:

```
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;



public class Downloader {
    public static void downloadFile(String address, String outputFileName) throws IOException {
        Log.e("JAVA_FILE_DOWNLOADER", "0");
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Log.e("JAVA_FILE_DOWNLOADER", "1");
        try
        {
            Log.e("JAVA_FILE_DOWNLOADER", "1.5");
            InputStream in = url.openStream();
            Log.e("JAVA_FILE_DOWNLOADER", "2");
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(in);
            Log.e("JAVA_FILE_DOWNLOADER", "3");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
            Log.e("JAVA_FILE_DOWNLOADER", "4");
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            Log.e("JAVA_FILE_DOWNLOADER", "5");
        }catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("JAVA_FILE_DOWNLOADER", "exception catched 1", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have the code running in a thread:

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Downloader.downloadFile("http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip", "/sdcard/data/Cat03.jpg");;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

The code fails after printing `JAVA_FILE_DOWNLOADER 1.5"`. and the stacktrace reads as the following:

```
 java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com": No address associated with hostname
     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
     at worldline.atos.com.spicatemplate.Downloader.downloadFile(Downloader.java:27)
     at worldline.atos.com.spicatemplate.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:178)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
     at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
    ... 15 more
```

Can some one please tell me what to do?

Comment: `No address associated with hostname` system can't resolve ip address from hostname, means there is no access to any DNS. so you probably don't have internet connection, is your address working in e.g. web browser?

Comment: @snachmsm . I am also downloading the same file with ION on the same device without a problem.

Comment: does your app have INTERNET access permission granted? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: @snachmsm yes it has all the required permission. and I am downloading the same file inside the same application with ION without a problem.